# Getting 'Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tablesorter is not a function' using webpack

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, npm, webpack, yarnpkg

I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tablesorter is not a function` after migrating to Rails 6 with Webpack. Here is my environment.js

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    tablesorter: 'tablesorter',
    bootstrap: 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap',
    draggable: 'plain-draggable'
  })
)

module.exports = environment
```

The other plugins associated are working correctly.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Did you resolve this? I'm having a similar problem and would be grateful for your advice. Thank you

Comment: @d_a_n note I'm the _editor_ - I just fixed the tags and formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly why, but it works by doing like this:

```
import $ from 'jquery'
import 'tablesorter'

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', () => {
  $('.tablesorter').tablesorter()
})
```